# ADFS + IdentityServer4 + MSIS9642 unable to construct an id token

Tags: identityserver4, adfs

Our requirement is to set up auth through ADFS.
The IdentityServer is for logging in.
We need the ADFS because we a SharePoint and we have multiple Claim Providers.

What we try to do:

```
SPA <--> ADFS <--> IdentityServer
```

**URLS**

```
SPA: https://example.com/app  
ADFS: http://fedsrv.example.com/adfs  
ID: https://idp.example.com/spa
```

**ADFS**
In ADFS we set up an application Group: `OIDC_SPA` with a native application `Portal` and a Web API `Portal`.

The native app does have a client ID: `example` and a redirect URI:
`https://example.com/app`

The Web API does have a Relying party identifiers: `example`,
has `Permit everyone` policy
and a transform rule `PT all` : `x:[] => issue(claim = x);`
and Client Permission `allatclaims, opened and profile`

The Claims Provider Trust is configured as following:
CP Federation metadata URL: `https://idp.example.com/spa/wsfed/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`
The CP identifier is `https://idp.example.com/spa`
WS-Fed Passive Endpoints is: `https://idp.example.com/spa/wsfed`

we also set the AnchorClaimType:

```
set-adfsclaimsprovidertrust -targetidentifier https://idp.example.com/spa -AnchorClaimType http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name
```

and for home realm mapping:

```
Set-AdfsWebApiApplication -TargetName OIDC_SPA -ClaimsProviderName "<CP name>"
```

**IdentityServer**
We added a client with ClientID `http://fedsrv.example.com/adfs/services/trust`
ProtocolTyp: wsfed

*RelyingParties:*

```
| Field                    | Value   |
|--------------------------|--------|
| Realm                    | http://fedsrv.example.com/adfs/services/trust         |
| TokenType                | urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion |
| SignatureAlgorithm       | http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 |
| DigestAlgorithm          | http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256               |
| SamlNameIdentifierFormat | urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified |
```

*IdentityResources*
There is `opened` and `profile` configured.

did we forget something or did we configure something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was, that the claims were not correctly mapped in the `Application Group` and `Claims Provider trust`.